# Does the python for loop end abruptly while checking a condition provided in form of a defined function?

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I was completing the code, for going through a pandas dataframe, to identify the column with maximum Nan Values, and replacing them with 1.

Below is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def isNaN(num):
    return num != num
c=0
d={}
data=pd.read_excel('File.xlsx')
for i in data[:]:
    c=0
    d[i]=c
    for j in data[i]:
        if isNaN(j):
            c=c+1
            d[i]=c
            data[:].replace(np.nan,1,inplace=True)
print(d)
print('the column with maximum Nan values is',list(d.keys())[list(d.values()).index(max(d.values()))],'with',max(d.values()),'nan values')
```

The loop seems to work only for the first column, that is the dictionary (d) which ideally should contain the column names as keys and number of 'Nan values' as values, only the first row's first Nan value is being counted.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You really must provide a [mcve] and a better description of the problem. That being said, this is totally the wrong way to use `pandas`.

Comment: `list(d.keys())[list(d.values()).index(max(d.values()))]` should just be `max(d, key=d.get)` but really, you should just be doing something like `max_key, max_value = max(d.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])`

Comment: What is this supposed to do??? `data[:].replace(np.nan,1,inplace=True)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga its supposed to replace the nan value with 1

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'll make changes to the last line, yet the problem persists

Comment: Why did you do `data[:]`? In any case, it replaces *all* the `NaN` values, so after that line, there will be no more nan's. Which I think may be your problem, because when you find the first NAN, you immediately remove all NANs, so no other row will have any NANs

Comment: But really, I think you just need something like `df.isna().sum().idxmax()`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I believe you are right about that data[:] part. How do I resolve it to replace only that particular nan value?

Comment: Stop doing a loop like this at all, as I explained, you should probably ust be able to do something like `df.isna().sum().idxmax()`

Comment: Note, the fact that it is replacing *all* isn't because you do `data[:]`, it would be the same with `data`. In any case, you can also use `data.at[i, j] = 1`, but you *really* shouldn't be working with pandas this way

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I understand. I'll remove the loops and try the code again whilst taking your suggestions into consideration, Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to do with your approach, but I think what you can do is simply:

```
print('the column with maximum Nan values is ' + df.isna().sum().idxmax() +' with '+str(df.isna().sum().max())+ ' nan values')
```

and then:

```
df[df.isna().sum().idxmax()].fillna(1,inplace=True)
```